# How do display error when submitting django form with jquery

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

am trying to do a password change form, but am submitting the form using jquery, my problem is that when a user submits a form with the wrong password, i cannot get the error message like if the new password and the confirm new password do not match, it will display that both passwords do not match, or if the old password is wrong, it will display that password is not correct,

Here is my code

profile.html

```
<form action="." enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="PassChan__form"> {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Change Your paswsord</legend>
        <input type="hidden" value="Chan_Pass" name="hidden_data" />
        {{ c_form | crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <h6 id="PassChan__show"></h6>
        <img src="{% static 'images/ajax-loader.gif' %}" style="Display:none;" id="PassChan__img">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit"  onclick="submit_form('PassChan__form', 'PassChan__submit', 'PassChan__img', 'PassChan__show', 'no')" id="PassChan__submit">Change Password</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':            
        response_data = {
            'SType': 'danger',
            'message': "An Error Occured, pls try again later"
        }
        c_form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            c_form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, c_form.user)
            response_data = {
                'SType': 'success',
                'message': "Your Password was changed successfully"
            }

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
    context={
        'c_form':PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

pls how can i do this

Comment: Based on your code you are passing back to jquery either `An Error Occured, pls try again later` or `Your Password was changed successfully`.  You need to capture error messages from the form when it is invalid but there is no code to do that.

Comment: i know, but how can i capture error messages from the form

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (this will require some change but should push you in the right direction):

```
 if c_form.is_valid():
        c_form.save()
        update_session_auth_hash(request, c_form.user)
        response_data = {
            'SType': 'success',
            'message': "Your Password was changed successfully"
        } 
else :
    response_data = {
         'SType' : 'error'
         'message' : c_form.errors
    }
```

Comment: you can access individual form fields with `c_form['fieldname']`

Comment: i tried  it but it didnt display the error but when i printed the c_form.errors in views.py it printed the ul html tags of the error message, so i used strip_tags(c_form.errors) it gave me this error message in the html old_password Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again.new_password2The two password fields didn't match.   How can i remove the old_password  in the error message

Comment: If you want the `old_password` error message to not occur then you've either got to pass the right `old_password` or subclass the form and remove that validation.

Comment: i want it to show "Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again.new_password2The two password fields didn't match" instead of "old_password Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again. The two password fields didn't match"

Comment: You can choose what you put in the error message - you know how to get ths info now